# How to pass string type to struct

Tags: c

I want pass a string type in C to my `struct`.

When I get from file using this:

```
int fd = open("file.txt",O_RDONLY);
read(fd, &mst, sizeof(struct my_struct);
```

is all right. But I want get from a `char *` type, exist some way to get from a `const char *` type using read method?

```
typedef struct{
    char a[3];
    char b[3];
}my_struct;

int main(){
    const char *str = "qwerty";
    my_struct mst;
    read(str,&mst, sizeof(my_struct));
}
```

Comment: Don't describe your code that doesn't work, show it.

Comment: You probably want `strncpy()`, not `read()`

Comment: Note: A `char *` is a **pointer**.  In C, a _string_ in a character **array** up to and including the terminating null character.

Comment: It worked, but a try add a `int` field in struct and did not work.

Comment: What is `my_struct`? It's never declared.

Comment: You don't show the complementary code to write the file. You have to be very careful. Depending on the platform and the data types, there can be "un-named" holes in structures, for alignment. Or the file could come from a machine with different Endian. That's where serialization or something like JSON are indicated.

Comment: This is actually the use-case that `strncpy` was designed for (using a terminated string to fill a fixed-length space without termination)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Thanks by tips guys, I solve my problem with this function.**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct __attribute__((__packed__)){
    char *s;
    int *x;
}my_struct;

void *chr2struct(const char *text){
    char c;
    my_struct *mst = (my_struct *) malloc(sizeof(my_struct));
    void **swap = (void **) malloc(sizeof(my_struct));
    void **res = swap;

    if(!text)
        return 0;

    int i;
    while(*text){
        c = *text;
        text++;
        char str[32];
        int x, len;
        char *data;
        switch(c){
            case 's':
            case 'c':
                sscanf(text,"%[^\037]",str);
                text += strlen(str)+1;
                len = atoi(str);
                data = (void *) malloc(sizeof(char)*len);
                strcpy(data,text);
                text+= len+1;
                swap[i] = data;
                break;
            case 'i':
                sscanf(text,"%[^\037]",str);
                text += strlen(str)+1;
                len = atoi(str);
                data = (void *) malloc(sizeof(int)*len);
                for(x=0; x<len; x++){
                    sscanf(text,"%i",&data[x]);
                    sprintf(str,"%i",data[x]);
                    text+=strlen(str)+1;
                    swap[i] = *data;
                }
                break;
            default:
                return 0;
        }
        i++;
    }

    return res;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    my_struct *mst;
    mst = (my_struct *) chr2struct("s16\037qwertyuiopasdfgh\0i1\03716\0");
    printf("%s | %i\n", mst->s, mst->x);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Reading from a text file directly into a struct is... odd.  Reading directly to a struct usually implies you're loading a binary data structure, not text.

It "works" because your struct is set up oddly.  A normal struct uses pointers to store strings, like so.

```
typedef struct {
    char *a;
    char *b;
} normal_struct;
```

If you wanted to put text into that struct, you'd assign a string (ie. a `char *`) to either `thing->a` or `thing->b`.

```
/* Allocate memory for the string in the struct */
thing->a = malloc(...);

...use thing->a like any other char *...
```

So you'd `read()` into `thing->a`, not into `thing`.

Putting a `char *` into this struct is easy.  Just assign it... and be sure to free whatever was already in `thing->a`.

```
if( thing->a != NULL )
    free(thing->a);

thing->a = str;
```

---

What you've done instead is created a struct with fixed size strings.

```
typedef struct {
    char a[3];
    char b[3];
} my_struct;
```

The first three bytes are `a` and the second three bytes are `b`.

When you `read` into `my_struct` the first 3 bytes of the text file become `a` and the second become `b`.  If the file is `foobarbaz` then `mst->a` is `foo` and `mst->b` is `bar`.

But since you just jammed characters in there, there's no null padding on those strings. C doesn't know how long they are.  Something like `printf("%s\n", mst->a)` is likely to produce `foobarald;kfjl2` as it reads garbage outside the struct until it happens to see a null.

For this, and many other reasons, you are much better off building your struct with `char *`s.

Comment: It's not "odd" or non-normal for a struct to contain arrays

Comment: @M.M I'm sure there are reasons to do it, a small three character flag for example, but it's unlikely they apply to the poster's problem.

Comment: well, he did say that `read(fd, &mst, sizeof(struct my_struct));` worked correctly

Comment: @M.M No, it happened to appear to work. Someone who is trying to use `read()` to copy strings into a struct, and posted code with syntax errors, cannot evaluate whether C code is working correctly. Lacking more information about what is being read, and that it is coming from a `.txt` file, and that doesn't know about `str*cpy`, that is what I have to assume.